# Determine all child elements width

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a method i can do to determine all child elements width in a single line of code. Adding up all child widths

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This?

```
var width = 0;
$('selector > *').each(function() { width += $(this).width(); });
```

[**jsFiddle example**](http://jsfiddle.net/LK3QX/)

Comment: This will not be limited to child elements.

Answer (score 5):

If you only want children elements, do this:

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/PV2dR/

```
var t=0;
$('#parent > *').width(function(i,w){t+=w;});
```

Or you can do this with the same outcome:

```
var t=0;
$('#parent').children().width(function(i,w){t+=w;});
```